# Updatable text field

Tags: ios

This will probably be very simple for many of you. I have been asked to build a very simple iPhone app in Xcode which when the view is loaded will update a text field with a sentence of text (That will be updated daily). I have been trying to research this however struggling a little to find the right thing.

Someone will update a DB with the sentence of text which will then be fed to the text field.

I know this is a very open question but could someone just point me in the direction of how to do this and I can research it myself?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, simply to start you will need to get a URL which will point to the content that you want. You can then grab this really easily with the following. Please note this is not the best method of doing so, but if you are new to iOS I am not going to get into the most optimized solution.

```
NSString *phrase = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://yourURL.com"]];
```

Then this can be applied to a simple `UILabel`.

```
someLabel.text = phrase;
```

Of course there is more to actually adding the button and whatnot, but you can find that in a standard tutorial anywhere online